# Find pairs in 2 files that are too large to fit in memory

Tags: algorithm, memory, language-agnostic

I'm looking for a memory efficient way to find pairs in 2 possibly very large files (can be as large as 1TB each) that do not fit into memory. For the sake of simplicity let's say the file contains just integers, but they are unordered and not each integer needs to exist in the other file.

I thought about using an external sorting to sort each file, then read the first entry from each file, and use the following pseudologic:

(`read_file()` would return something that which you can compare, and call `advance()` on to shift the cursor to the next line)

```py
left_file = read_file("file-1.txt")
right_file = read_file("file-2.txt")

while (there_are_entries_in_either_file):
    if left_file == right_file:
        # write match to output
        left_file.advance()
        right_file.advance()
    elif left_file < right_file:
        # if left is smaller then we can skip that entry
        left_file.advance()
    elif right_file < left_file:
        # if right is smalelr then we can skip that entry
        right_file.advance()
```

This would in theory work, but would limit me to a single thead, which would not be very fast.

The process with example data would look like (left column is file 1, right column is file 2)

```
1   1
2   5
3   6
5   7
```

1. We read `1` from both left and right, it matches so we advance both files
2. We read `2` from left and `5` from right, left is smaller, so we discard the `2` and advance left
3. We read `3` from left and still have the `5` from right, left is stills maller so we discard `3` and advance left
4. We read `5` from left and still have the `5` from right, which now matches so we advance both
5. repeat...

Are there any algorithms that would allow me to match pairs in a multithreaded way?

Comment: The cost of disk IO will (or at least should) dominate CPU cost, so I don't think multithreading will help you much. Sharding (making sure to write the sharded data in a compact form if the originals are inefficiently stored for example as text), and then matching inside the shards is likely to be best if the (compactified) data really doesn't fit in memory. Baseline your measurements on the cost of reading and writing 1TB of data. A read of 1TB may take 6 minutes if you have a fast SSD, over 30 minutes if you have a slower SSD, and 3-4 times longer than that if you have a spinning disk.

Answer (score 1):

The correct way of solving this is using [MapReduce](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MapReduce) which will help to divide these huge files into smaller chunks and once you have the result, you merge them back into a single output.

If you are not looking to setup a cluster for this purpose , you could follow the same algorithm on a single node as well.

Rough pseudocode:

1. Split both the files into `x` parts. (say 1000 1GB files or maybe even smaller).
2. Write a logic that takes 1 part file from each of the 2 sets and tries to match them by your logic. If matches are there, store them in part_a1_b1_output. Also, make sure that if splitting leads to some metadata loss, try to find an alternate way to compute it.
3. Once you have all the output files ready, do an n-way merge to get the final result.

But if you use an actual cluster, this can be rather quickly.

Comment: Hmm, but then in the case that some items from set 1, lets say number 1001 ends up in the second chunk, and due to missing numbers before that number 1001 of set 2 ends up in the first chunk, no match would be found across that boundary.

Comment: @Oreborous value N goes into shard HASH(N) % M, so matching values always go into the same shard.

Comment: `1. Split both the files into x parts` is a bit thin, and little use if "pairs" didn't end up in *corresponding* parts: How to make it highly likely that no pair of part overtaxes resources?

Comment: If your data is already on a cluster then it's different, but the overhead from copying 2TB to the cluster and then 1TB of result back is a fairly big overhead if you have data on a single machine, even with a fast network connection. My money would be on a single machine with just a single large fast SSD against map-reduce with the copy to&from the cluster.